# Мужское имя Алекса и город Алексин

Tags: этимология, ономастика, история, топонимика, антропонимика

Название города Алексина этимологически восходит к сочетанию *Алексинъ городъ*, т. е. «город Алексы». Алекса, как сообщается, есть сокращение имени Александр.

Верно ли это? Действительно ли было такое мужское имя? Когда оно использовалось?

Answer (score 2):

Имя Александр произошло от древнегреческого имени Александрос, которое состоит из двух частей – «алексо» (букв. «защищать») и «андрос» (букв. «мужчина»). Александр переводится как «защищающий людей». На Русь пришло с православием как крестильное имя, звучало в быту как Олекса (где было оканье) и Алекса (где акали), но Олексами - Алексами вплоть до середины 19 века называли и Алексеев.

Об истоках названия города Алексина не все источники говорят одинаково. Впервые  о нём упоминается в Никоновской летописи под 1348 годом:

> «...князь Темир Ординский приходи ратью ко граду Олексину святыго
>   чудотворца Петра, митрополита Киевского и всея Руси, и посад пожже…».

Самая старая и наиболее распространенная в исторической литературе версия впервые  была озвучена в начале XIX столетия в статье «Алексин» на страницах «Словаря географического Российского государства», изданного в Москве Афанасием Щекатовым в 1801 – 1809 годах:

> Некоторые повествуют, что сей город (Алексин. – С.Г.) одолжен своим
>   началом Князю Даниилу Александровичу Московскому, сыну Великаго Князя
>   Александра Ярославича Невскаго, которой имея свое пребывание в Москве,
>   во время объезду его для осматривания около лежащих мест, в тех
>   урочищах, где теперь город Алексин, получил радостное известие о
>   рождении ему сына Алексея Даниловича; по чему тогда же и приказал
>   заложить сей город, наименовав его Алексином; а в Истории сына Алексея
>   у Князя Даниила Московскаго не упоминается» (Указ. соч. С.116–117).

Известно, что у кн. Даниила осталось пять сыновей: **Юрий, Иван (Калита), Александр, Афанасий и Борис.**

В 1841 году в работе ученого-статистика И.В. Линка (1813 – 1864) – «Историко-статистический взгляд на города Тульской губернии» версия  была подвергнута жесткой критике: "Сказка, довольно часто повторяющаяся..."

В 1844 году в «Тульских губернских ведомостях» (№№ 9 – 12) краевед и историк  И.Ф.Афремов поддерживает старую версию:

> «Древнее предание о начале города гласит следующее: московский
>   удельный князь Даниил Александрович, сын Св. Александра Невского,
>   обозревая свои области, прибыл к Оке и, перешед реку, был обрадован
>   московским гонцом о счастливом рождении сына его Алексея, и на том
>   самом месте, где получил радостную весть эту, 1298 года заложил новое
>   городище с тайником, шедшим к реке и назвал его по имени сына своего
>   «Олексиным», который потом первым Московским великим князем Иоанном
>   Даниловичем Калитою был отдан с рыбными ловлями Св. Петру митрополиту,
>   перенесшему кафедру свою из Владимира в Москву 1323 года» и далее в
>   сноске № 4: «В старину имя это писалось «Олексе». Малыгин (З.Р.Г., ст.
>   300) не упоминает в «Генеалогии» о сыне сего московского князя
>   Алексее; вероятно скончавшемся в младенчестве; тем не менее древнее
>   предание это об Алексине, выписанное кн. Щербатовым из летописей под
>   1298 годом прямо отвергать не возможно. Легенда присовокупляет еще,
>   что князь Даниила встретил здесь отшельник Сарвил и предсказал ему
>   рождение сына». (Тульские губернские ведомости. 1844. № 9).

Из приведенного отрывка видно, что автор пытается оправдать версию ссылкой на возможную раннюю смерть сына Даниила Александровича московского Алексея и князя М.М.Щербатова, который будто бы выписал это предание об основании Алексина из летописей под 1298 годом.

. http://www.aleksin-city.info/gorod/history/predanie-legenda-skazka.html

Так что всё это предания, но версия эта может иметь под собой историческое основание в том случае, если сын Даниила Александровича Алексей умер в раннем возрасте. В современных же словарях приводится имя Александра, сына князя Московского Даниила. Какого сына они имеют в виду - Александра или Алексея - вряд ли мы теперь узнаем.

Answer (score 1):

Если возводить основу к имени собственному, то тогда это **Алекся** и уменьшительное к Алексей или Александр.

Но я думаю, что скорее всего "Алексин" звался уже сам основатель, мифический или реальный, города. Отцом его мог быть Александр или Алексей, тогда Алексин - это своеобразное отчество.

> Согласно преданиям, Алексин был основан в конце XIII века первым
>   московским князем Даниилом Александровичем, младшим сыном Александра
>   Невского...

(Вики)

Тут немного смущает только само образование "Алекса" от Александр. Ну с чего бы представителю княжеского рода уничижительное имя носить?!